# Building Ionic 3 app with Quickblox JS package give 'child_process' error

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, quickblox

First of all, I created a blank project through the ionic blank project. Then added quickblox API javascript packages with npm :

`npm install quickblox --save`

Now when building this projects for ios or android with this command "ionic cordova build ios/android" I this error -- "Error: ./~/node-xmpp-client/lib/Client.js"

I have also added the node-xmpp-client package in my project by adding

`npm install --save node-xmpp-client`

Screenshot attached

[image: XMPP Client.js Error]

I am still getting the same issue.

Please help this issue Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I have the same exact issue

Comment: is anyone found a solution for this problem, facing the same issue after installing in ionic 3

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I made a Demo https://github.com/niccolofanton/quickblox-ionic3

**Old answer:**
I've found a solution, in your index.html put this:

Ionic:

```
<script>
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

      function onDeviceReady() {

          var loadScriptAsync = function(path){
              var jsScript = document.createElement("script");
              jsScript.type = "text/javascript";
              jsScript.async = false; //async is being set to false so that script will not immediately fire.
              jsScript.src = path;
              document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(jsScript);
          }
          loadScriptAsync("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quickblox/2.11.0/quickblox.min.js");
      }

</script>
```

Simple angular:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quickblox/2.11.0/quickblox.min.js"></script>
```

Then in your provider outside the class, under the imports:

```
declare var QB: any;
```

The full guide for Ionic/Cordova it's here:
https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-cordova